# How to detect Back button click in Durandal

Tags: javascript, jquery, durandal

Is there any possibility in **Durandal** to detect that Back button was clicked? I have inspected the **router** module but unfortunately didn't found any indicator of back navigation.

I need this functionality in *activate()* method. In case Back button is clicked I will not send additional request to server but try to load data from a cache.

Comment: I don't think you can detect the back button specifically, but the router has `navigatingBack` as a property.

Comment: You are saving a lot of my time with your precious comment. It's sad I couldn't find this property documented anywhere. Is this because it isn't to be used with production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery to find that:

```
$(window).on("popstate")
```

You can write your own service which will be toggle state of a global flag based on how the navigation is happening. When the navigation is through back button set the flag to 1 and unset it if its not.

Comment: Thank you! I've choosen a little different approach with using of *onbeforeunload* event but it's almost the same.